# How to send data to another component in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I want to pass data to another component but not like this.*

```
  return (
              <View style = {{flex:1}}>

   --->   <LoginForm  profile = {this.state.values}/> // I dont want to send like this

                <Animated.View style={{ ...this.props.style, opacity: fadeAnim }} >
                {this.props.children}

                </Animated.View>

              </View>

            );
```

*because if I do like this, this component includes LoginForm as well. and also I dont want to send with navigate. Because I dont  want to open that component on screen. when I work in this screen I just want to send values to another component*

Comment: How does the current component relates to `LoginForm`? Is `LoginForm` the parent component of the current component?

Comment: it is parent component

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to mutate the state from `LoginForm` to this child component.

On `LoginForm`,

```js
<View>
...
  <ChildComponent changeProfile={(profile) => {
    this.setState({
      profile: profile
    })
  }}/>
</View>
```

then on this `ChildComponent`, call

```js
this.props.changeProfile(this.state.values);
```

Or you can try a state management library too, like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html). Personally, I prefer Redux.